# using fancybox rel=group on one img and jQuery img src change

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I've a very specific question reffering to [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). My markup looks like this:

```
<a id="fancy_link" class="fancybox" href="image.jpg" rel="group"> 
  <img id="image" src="image.jpg" style="height: 500px;">
</a>
```

it is one image which works fine so far. But since I have a lot of images (200) I want to group, and don't want to hardcode each one of them in the markup I'm using a simple jQuery function:

```
function changeImg(e, f) {
  $('#fancy_link').attr('href', e[f].img);
  $("#image").attr('src', e[f].img);
}
```

`e`and `f` are the image links which are saved in an Array object namend `.img`

So my question now is, if you know how I could handle it, that fancybox creates group elements even if there is only one `<img>` element in the markup and it goes through all images when I click the prev and next button which come with fancybox.

Comment: Could you add the values of `e[f]` in comment after the line?

Comment: Why not just add a class and do somethings like `$('.ImagesYouWant').attr('rel','group1').fancybox();`

Comment: sorry but could you post this as a detailed answer, that I get how to do that.

Comment: That was the whole post :P you add a class to all the images you (or another selector, like `$(#wrapper).find('img')`) and add the rel to it, then fancybox it

Comment: oh I think I explained myself a little bit bad. I have only one `<img>` tag in my markup, and I want fancybox to have prev and next on the same image by firing the `changeImg()`

Comment: You want arrows with only 1 image? That's bad for user experience, it's not here for a reason!

Comment: there are 200 images, but I want to display them all through 1 image tag. When I press prev and next it should change the imagesrc.

Answer (score 1):

After one of your comments, I got what you mean. That would be weird to to, And kinda unexpected if you dont know this code and look into it. I asume you only want to display the first:

```
<div>
   <img src="1.jpg" alt="img1" rel="group1" />
   <img src="2.jpg" alt="img2" rel="group1" />
   <img src="3.jpg" alt="img3" rel="group1" />
   <img src="4.jpg" alt="img4" rel="group1" />
   <img src="5.jpg" alt="img5" rel="group1" />
</div>


div img{ display: none; }
div img:nth-child(1){ display: inline-block;}
```

This code makes more sence to other users. The pro here is that all the images will preload. The con here is that all the images will preload (I know, double). You have a large amount of images, which can take a chuck out of the bandwidth of a user.

---

If you have all the paths top the images in an array, you can do something like this:

```
$.each(imageArr, function(key,image){
    $img = $( document.createElement('img') );
    $img[0].src = image.img; // img is the key in the object
    $('div').append($img);
})
```

This is a bit more complex, and might complicate some eventhandling, but you do have more control over the images getting loaded. You can change this to something that loads two at a time and then does the next

Comment: thats not exactly what I intend to do but kind of solves the problem. I wanted to avoid to create all image elements into the body, I wanted to change just the image source of one `<img>` tag when I'm pressing the `prev` or `next` buttons of fancybox, but I pressume that would be go to much into the code of fancybox to make that.

Comment: If you want to go JS on this, I suggest the 2nd method. Still no hardcoding needed, and a lot better to maintain

Comment: one question, could you adjust your answer that the `each` function contains the array element I have all my paths in. Which is `var imageArr = [{ img: 'linktoimage' }, { img: 'linktoimage2'}, /* .. */];`

Comment: Editted it, just read up on jquery's each with arrays, it'll give you a better insight